# How to add NSString's to email using setMessageBody

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios5, nsstring, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement an autofilled email. I have the emailviewcontroller popping into place correctly in a separate test environment, but I cant work out how to add strings to the message body. Basically I have three buttons on the root controller of the gui that set the values of three strings. All I want is for those three strings to be be reproduce (if possible separated by commas) in the message body. Here is my code so far:

```
    -(IBAction)displayComposerSheet
    {

    NSArray *recipient = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"testemail@office.co.uk", nil];

    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
            MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]             init];
        mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailViewController setSubject:@"Place holder ... this is a test subject"];
        [mailViewController setMessageBody: isHTML:NO];
        [mailViewController setToRecipients:recipient];


        [self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Device is unable to send email in its current state");

    }

    -(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller     didFinishWithREsult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
- (IBAction)addString1:(id)sender {

    NSString *string1;
    string1 = @"teststring1";

}

- (IBAction)addString2:(id)sender {

    NSString *string2;
    string2 = @"teststring2";
}

- (IBAction)addString3:(id)sender {
    NSString *string3;
    string3 = @"teststring3";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you'll want to declare your strings in your .h file so that you can use them throughout the .m

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *string1;
    NSString *string2;
    NSString *string3;
}
```

Then in the mail composer you'll use a formatted string to display your strings in sequence (escaped by %@)

```
    [mailViewController setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@",string1,string2,string3] isHTML:NO];
```

Of course after declaring your strings in your header file there will be no need to declare them locally so change your IBActions to look like this:

```
   - (IBAction)addString1:(id)sender 
    {
        string1 = @"teststring1";
    }

    - (IBAction)addString2:(id)sender 
    {
        string2 = @"teststring2";
    }

    - (IBAction)addString3:(id)sender 
    {
        string3 = @"teststring3";
    }
```

Additionally, to avoid unwanted instances of (null) being inserted into your message body I recommend you give these strings an initial blank value in viewDidLoad. This way the will start out without any content, but they won't be nil.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    string1 = @"";
    string2 = @"";
    string3 = @"";
}
```

Comment: Ah brilliant, thank you! Is there any way to have those strings assigned in my .h based on user input at runtime?

Comment: @Refllux The way I've showed you will declare the strings and instantiate them when the app finishes loading, then they are populated with your content once the user presses the button. And if my answer helped you please don't forget to mark it as correct by clicking the "check mark" next to my post!

Comment: It certainly did, thank very much indeed, just solved a problem I've had for a while. Thanks again!